# $A.util.addClass() and $A.util.removeClass() in Lightning Web Components

Tags: lightning-web-components

Does anyone know of an equivalent to the Aura utility methods for adding/ removing style classes dynamically, or have some other workaround?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_styles.htm

Comment: FYI, for most of the custom stuff you see in Aura, LWC does using native functionality. That's one reason why components are smaller and faster than in Aura.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the standard element classList property for it (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList))

Like:

Template

```
<template>
    <div>Hello World!</div>
    <lightning-button label="Add" onclick={addClass}></lightning-button>
    <lightning-button label="Remove" onclick={removeClass}></lightning-button>
    <lightning-button label="Toggle" onclick={toggleClass}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

Controller:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {

    addClass() {
        this.template.querySelector('div').classList.add('red');
    }

    removeClass() {
        this.template.querySelector('div').classList.remove('red');
    }

    toggleClass() {
        this.template.querySelector('div').classList.toggle('red');
    }
}
```

Example:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/b-iFXjvxr/1/edit

Comment: Links can go bad, Renji. Can you copy the relevant answers to the question here?

Comment: added the code example inline

Comment: Wonderful, thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much Renji