# Create an LWC from a LC - JavaScript Translation

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

Im new to developing Lightning Web Components (LWCs) but have created some Lightning Components (LCs). Im trying to reuse some of the javascript code I wrote in one of my LCs, but am having trouble converting it. Here is the function Im trying to recreate (questions below)...

```
showCard: function(component,activeCard) {
        var cards = component.find("cardContainer").get('v.body');
        for (var i=0; i<cards.length; i++) {
            if (activeCard == cards[i].getLocalId()) {
                $A.util.removeClass(cards[i],"card--off");
            } else {
                $A.util.addClass(cards[i],"card--off");
            }
        }
        component.set('v.currentView',activeCard);
    }
```

1. "component" doesn't appear to be a valid parameter any longer, what is the equivalent in LWC?
2. $A.util.addClass is no longer valid as well. What is its equivalent?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265148/a-util-addclass-and-a-util-removeclass-in-lightning-web-components/265155

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you want to highlight a card/element in an iteration and you are adding a class to highlight and removing that class to all other cards.

Here is the [Playground Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/CG_CS-BDl/3/edit) I have created for you.

**Below is the explanation:**

> "component" doesn't appear to be a valid parameter any longer, what is
>   the equivalent in LWC?

You should use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_dom_work) to get all cards elements and iterate through them to find the selected card and

> $A.util.addClass is no longer valid as well. What is its equivalent?

use [native java-script APIs/methods like classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

**HTML:**

```
    <template for:each={cards} for:item="card">
        <div data-card={card.id} class="slds-m-around_small" key={card.id}>
            <lightning-card title="Hello">
                <lightning-button label="Select"
                            data-button={card.id}
                            onclick={selectHandler} 
                            slot="actions">
                </lightning-button>
                <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">Card Body (custom component)</p>
                <p slot="footer">Card Footer</p>
            </lightning-card>
        </div>
    </template>
```

**JS:**

```
export default class App extends LightningElement {
    cards = [
        {id:'1', title: 'Title 1', body: 'Body 1'},
        {id:'2', title: 'Title 2', body: 'Body 2'},
        {id:'3', title: 'Title 3', body: 'Body 3'}
    ];

    selectHandler(event) {
        let clickedBtn = event.currentTarget.dataset.button;
        let cards = [];
        this.template.querySelectorAll('[data-card]').forEach(divElm=>{
            if(divElm.getAttribute('data-card') === clickedBtn) {
                divElm.classList.add('card_selected');
            } else {
                divElm.classList.remove('card_selected');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Very helpful!